# How to solve NameError in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm invoking one function using a button click. But it is giving me error: `NameError: global name 'new' is not defined` ,even though I have defined `new` as a new window.

My code for a new window:

```
def result():
  root.withdraw()
  new = Toplevel()
  new.geometry("1105x605+300+300")

  button3 = Button(new, text='Select a Query Image',command = matching_image)
  button3.pack(padx = 1, pady = 1,anchor='ne')
  button3.place( x = 570, y = 60)
```

The button will invoke `matching_image` function, and the code will be:

```
def matching_image():
  path1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image File",'.jpg')])
  im = Image.open(path1)
  resized = im.resize((200, 200),Image.ANTIALIAS)
  tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
  myvar1 = Label(new,image = tkimage)
  myvar1.image = tkimage
  myvar1.pack()
  myvar1.place(x = 30, y = 100)
```

And this is giving the error. The error message is as follows:

```
%run "D:/6th sem/Major project/Code/frame.py"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.0.3.1262.win-x86\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "D:\6th sem\Major project\Code\frame.py", line 194, in matching_image
myvar1 = Label(new,image = tkimage)

NameError: global name 'new' is not defined
```

Any suggestions! So that I can solve this error.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `new` in a function, so that variable only exists in that function's scope. Therefore, when you try to access it in another scope (here it is the global scope) you will get a `NameError` as it is not available at that level.

---

You can fix this by doing `global new` at the start of the function in which you define it.

This statement puts it in the global scope, meaning that it is defined at the module level. Therefore, you can access it anywhere in the program and you will not get that error.

Like this:

```
def result():
    global new
    new = Toplevel()
    # Other stuff.
```

Though note that doing global declarations is considered bad practice. Much better to put your code in `class` form and assign applicable variables to `self`.

Comment: @user3483746 If I resolved your issue, feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) after the fifteen minute grace period.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is condensed down to this:

```
def foo():
  var = 1

def bar():
  print var

foo()
bar()
```

The principle problem you have is that 'var' is a local, not a global.

This code example works:

```
def foo():
  global var
  var = 1

def bar():
  print var

foo()
bar()
```

Because var is declared to be global instead.